# Can I automate creating a .NET web application in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, installation

I need to deploy a web application on several laptops (although it is a web application, it is intended to run via `localhost` only - thus the need to deploy on several different machines).

Normally I would go to IIS and right click a directory to create a web application, but I would very much like to automate this leg of the installation. Can it be done?

**I want to use IIS, but I want to create the web application automatically without opening the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC).**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can suggest you to take a [look at this link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1805162e-6ac5-4a98-9a08-919c4c10827d.mspx?mfr=true) if you are deploying on IIS 6 [or at this one](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/) if it is IIS 7 (I could recommend [Mike Volodarsky's blog](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/default.aspx) for any information on IIS 7 in general).

It should be quite simple for you to write some batch file to automate a site creation.

Example:

- IIS6 : iisweb /create C:\Rome "My Vacations" /d www.reskit.com /dontstart
- IIS7 : %windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd ADD SITE /name:MyNewSite /bindings:http/*:81: /physicalPath:c:\inetpub\mynewsite

Answer (score 4):

You're really asking two different questions.  First, why reinvent the wheel?  In all likelihood, the laptops are already capable of running IIS - it's available on all "modern" Windows versions with the possible exception of Vista Home.  Second, a VS.NET installer can easily target and automate an install to IIS.  If you use Wix or some other third party installer it will require more manual work but can still be done.

Edit: In re-reading your question, that sounds like what you're really asking - you already knew IIS was available on the target computers, but just didn't want to manually install on each computer.  Correct?  In that case, definitely look at the VS.NET setup project - they have a built-in target for IIS deployment.

Comment: YES that is what I am talking about, I just edited the question :D Thx

Comment: +1 for reading the question. I was thinking "Mono" at first as well, but as it turns out the title has not much to do with the text...

Comment: I think that's because it was not in there to begin with. :-) I changed the title to what it is right now.

Comment: MSI package is nice if you just install one instance on one machine. If you want to install multiple instances, it will not be that easy.

Comment: @croc - but a packaged install is still easier than running multiple, completely manual installs, which is what the OP faced.  In some cases, packaged (MSI) installers can even be completely scripted and deployed through IT management tools from anywhere in the organization.  In fact, I'd argue the opposite - if you only are going to deploy one instance on one machine, why even bother with an MSI?

Answer (score 2):

To implement a minimal web server you can use HTTP.SYS (the core component of IIS deployed with Windows XP SP2 or higher). In .NET this can be done e.g. by using the HttpListener class in the [System.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net?view=netframework-4.8) namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can look inside the [Cassini Sample Web Server](http://www.asp.net/downloads/archived/cassini/) (comes with source):

> The ASP.NET Cassini Web Server Sample is a sample web server written using the Microsoft® .NET® Framework, and demonstrates hosting ASP.NET using the ASP.NET hosting APIs (System.Web.Hosting).

Answer (score 2):

You could also try [Mono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29). It is for Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows.

They have xsp a web server for .NET applications.

There is documentation about that in *[ASP.NET | Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the system.DirectoryServices class e.g.

http://www.gafvert.info/iis/article/cs_create_website_iis6.htm

Comment: The DirectoryServices works pretty well for creating a IIS6 website. It can also be used to IIS7 if IIS6 compatibility mode is turned one. For IIS7, you can also use Web Administration API. Both methods can be scripted in powershell. Maybe you can create powershell script to deploy the web site.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Visual Studio project of type "Setup and Deployment", and use the "Web Setup" type.

This will create an .msi installer that will automatically create the web app for you within IIS.

You will then also get the ability to perform network installs, so if you have the right permissions you could manage this centrally.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a virtual directory without using the MMC console using the WebDirectoryCreate task available inside the project [msbuildtasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Have look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/rmclaws/archive/2005/10/25/428422.aspx). It explains how to start [Cassini web server](https://www.developer.com/net/deciding-on-a-microsoft-web-server-cassini-iis-and-iis-express.html) from the command line and add it as a shell extension.

CarlosAg's blog has some great posts about [IIS administration throw PowerShell](http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosag/archive/2008/02/11/MicrosoftWebAdministrationInPowershell.aspx) and [managed code](http://blogs.msdn.com/carlosag/archive/2008/06/12/FasterIISProvisioningUsingMWA.aspx).

Comment: The last two links are (effectively) broken (redirects to a generic page, *"Archived MSDN and TechNet Blogs"*). It may or may not be possible to find them in the archive.