# Can I automate creating a .NET web application / virtual directory in IIS 5?

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-5

I asked this [Can I automate creating a .NET web application in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313877/can-i-automate-creating-a-net-web-application-in-iis) a little ago, and got solutions for IIS 6 and IIS 7:

- IIS6 : `iisweb /create C:\Rome "My
  Vacations" /d www.reskit.com
  /dontstart`
- IIS7 :
  `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd ADD
  SITE /name:MyNewSite
  /bindings:http/*:81:
  /physicalPath:c:\inetpub\mynewsite`

but I've just got back to it the actual project, and it turns out that is I need to deploy on (shock-horror) IIS 5.1

Has anyone got any ideas?

To make it clear:

**I want to use IIS, but I want to create the web application automatically (ideally batch file) without opening the IIS Microsoft Management Console (MMC)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the IIS 5.1 metabase in VBScript, and this allows you to create a virtual directory. For example, this should set up a Virtual Directory called 'TestDir' that points to the folder C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test

```
strComputer = "localhost"
strVdirName = "TestDir"
strVdirPath = "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test"

set objIIS = GetObject("IIS://" & strComputer & "/W3SVC/1")
set objWebSite = objIIS.GetObject("IISWebVirtualDir","Root")
set objVdir = objWebSite.Create("IISWebVirtualDir",strVdirName)
objVdir.AccessRead = True
objVdir.Path = strVdirPath
objVdir.AppCreate (True)
objVdir.SetInfo
WScript.Echo "Successfully created virtual directory: " & objVdir.Name
```

Comment: i think i owe you A BIG DRINK. kudos.