# How do I create an application in IIS 5.0 using powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis-5

I've worked out how to interact with IIS 6.0, but I can't find anything on the net about how to talk to IIS 5.0 - if indeed it's even possible?

I would like to write a script to create a temporary application, so I can copy some ASP.NET files there, build them, and then remove the temporary application.

If needs be I am happy to call a third-party VBScript instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There use to be some installers on the ASP.NET downloads that would setup a project in IIS 5.0.  I think it was the old ASP.NET Forums software.  I know this wasn't an answer to your question.

If I was a betting man I would say they probably created a batch file that used the VBScripts.  Because I remember a black window popping up to compile and deploy.

As far as PowerShell goes, I don't think there is any solution for integration with IIS 5.

Answer (score 0):

[Can I automate creating a .NET web application / virtual directory in IIS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371207/can-i-automate-creating-a-net-web-application-virtual-directory-in-iis-5#371264)