# Change IIS 5 virtual directory in Post-Build Event in Visual Studio

Tags: iis, batch-file, windows-xp, post-build-event

I'm running into an issue where I need to be able to change the target directory path that my IIS 5.0 virtual directory is pointing to from within a Post-Build block in Visual Studio 2008.

If you're not familiar with Post-Build events they basically just take batch commands. So if you know of a batch command for IIS 5.0 in XP Pro that can change the target directory that a virtual directory is pointing to that would really help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Can I automate creating a .NET web application / virtual directory in IIS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371207/can-i-automate-creating-a-net-web-application-virtual-directory-in-iis-5)
to run VBScript in command line, use CScript.

Comment: Great! Do you know of a way to specify the language in the post-build event? I know I can type in batch commands without needing to specify anything. For vbscript do I need to put a header or something at the top?

Comment: no, just add the location of cscript to your path. By default it is under C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! I ended up needing to make some changes so that it would just change the path of the virtual directory instead of creating it each time, but the changes were minor. Thanks!