# using appcmd to add new web site issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-7, appcmd

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + IIS 7.0. I want to using appcmd to add a new web site, my scenario is like this.

1. All my web site files are under folder c:\template;
2. I want to add my new web site as a virtual directory under default web site, the virtual directory is called "testsite1";
3. I want to use the default application pool (or the application pool which default web site is using).

I have stuied appcmd for quite some time, but cannot figure out. Maybe either I am too stupid or because IIS 7.0/appcmd is new, help information is limited. :-)

Appreciate if anyone could let me know how to complete my deployment task using appcmd?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: I would use the WMI library and add the site that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You must open the command prompt as Administrator
2. Execute the following:

   ```
   "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd" add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/testsite1 /physicalPath:"c:\template"
   ```

How I found this out? I did the following:

```
appcmd add app /?
```

and there was this example:

```
appcmd add app /site.name:"Default Web Site" /path:/app1
```

so I just added `physicalPath`

[check this also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313877/can-i-automate-creating-a-net-web-application-in-iis/313983#313983)